# React - using withRouter returns error "Cannot read property 'route' of undefined"

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-router, react-router-v4

I have a basic texting app where I want to check everytime the page pathname is changed, and do a function.  I have the components working correctly so far, its just when I started to organize my code and started using withRouter that I got an error as such:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'route' of undefined
```

If I remove the withRouter it works fine running the isUserAuthenticated function.  What could I do to change my code so that it works with withRouter while providing the same functions as it does.  Right now the error that it returns is just a blank white page with no components being rendered to the screen

**routes.js**

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
import React from "react";
import { Meteor } from "meteor/meteor";

import App from "./../ui/App";
import NotFound from "./../ui/NotFound";
import Signup from "./../ui/Signup";
import Login from "./../ui/Login";

class Routes extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }
    isUserAuthenticated(){
        let isAuthenticated = !!Meteor.userId();
        console.log(this.props.history)
        if(isAuthenticated){

        }
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Switch>
                    <App path="/chat" texts={this.props.texts} render={this.isUserAuthenticated()}/>
                    <Signup path="/signup" render={this.isUserAuthenticated()}/>
                    <Login path="/" render={this.isUserAuthenticated()}/>
                    <Route path="*" component={NotFound}/>
                </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
}
export default withRouter(Routes)
```

I have read somewhere that using super(props) in the constructor will fix this problem(which I doubted from the beginning) and it still gave me the same error.

Comment: `I want to check everytime the page pathname is changed` - I assume you need this for the `App`, `Signup` and `Login`. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: What if you remove `withRouter` from `Routes`, but add it to the `App`, `Signup` and `Login`? Since those are the components that need to access the pathname.

Comment: What do you mean?  How would I do that...I just started Meteor excuse my noob questions

Comment: Honestly, I am still trying to figure out where the issue is. Since you only provided a small part of your codes. Based on the error, I suspect that some of your components did not have access to the `props` provided by `route`. In your codes, `App`, `Signup` and `Login` fall to this qualification. You need to export them using `withRouter` to make it works. For example in `App.js`, you need to use `export default withRouter(App)` so the `App` have access to `props.match` and `props.location`. Again, this is just my preliminary assumption.. need to check the full codes to be sure.